# How can I catch esbuild's build error and run a script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, esbuild

Is there a way to catch esbuild's build error and run a script?
I'm using it with npm, VSCode, and vanilla JS.

I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 1):

esbuild uses promises, so you can catch errors as usual

```js
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild'

try {
  await esbuild.build({
    entryPoints: ['app.ts'],
    bundle: true,
    outdir: 'dist',
  });
} catch {
  // build failed
}

// or
esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['app.ts'],
  bundle: true,
  outdir: 'dist',
}).catch(() => {
  // build failed
});
```

Comment: Where should I run this code from? And will it catch errors from subsequent builds without initialization?

Comment: This uses the esbuild JS API as opposed to running the CLI. You can add such code in a script file (e.g build.mjs), then run it from node (e.g. node ./build.mjs)

Comment: Why can't I run any script at all? I only want a beep to warn for errors, I tried the well-known process.stdout.write('\u0007');  - it didn't work, alert("ERROR!") didn't work, I even tried it in package.json "build": "node ./build.mjs || 'process.stdout.write('\u0007')", and only works the 1st time I manually start the build,  nothing works, development idiocy at its finest!

Comment: @dllb you can use: `console.log("message")`, or `esbuild.build({/* build options */}).catch((err) => { console.error(err) });`

Comment: That catches the errors and works with 'process.stdout.write('\u0007')' to output a system sound, but it doesn't watch for changes, with the following code it watches for changes but it doesn't catch errors - go figure!
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild'
let ctx = await esbuild.context({
 entryPoints: ['./src/main.js'],
 minify: true,
 sourcemap: true,
 bundle: true,
 outdir: 'dist',
 logLevel: 'info'
}).catch(() => { 
 process.stdout.write('\u0007');
})
await ctx.watch()
console.log('watching...')